# Issue `ZERO_OUTSTANDING_BALANCE` when Capturing authorized payment just after creating subscription in `PAYPAL`

Tags: php, laravel, paypal, laravel-8

**Getting below error when Capturing authorized payment just after creating subscription in `PAYPAL`**. if anyone have idea about why it's happening or got any solution, please reply.

code for capturing the payment of given subscription id. which giving below included error.

```
$provider = new PayPalClient;
$provider->getAccessToken();
$response = $provider->captureSubscriptionPayment($request->input('subscription_id'), 'capturing payment', (float)$package->price);
```

Error:-

```
`{
    "name":"UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY",
    "message":"The requested action could not be performed, semantically incorrect, or failed business validation.",
    "debug_id":"2e3384fe1998b",
    "details":[
        {
            "issue":"ZERO_OUTSTANDING_BALANCE",
            "description":"Current outstanding balance should be greater than zero."
        }
    ],
    "links":[
        {
            "href":"https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/v1/billing/subscriptions#UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY",
            "rel":"information_link","method":"GET"
        }
    ]
}`

{
    "name":"UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY",
    "message":"The requested action could not be performed, semantically incorrect, or failed business validation.",
    "debug_id":"b1c0f40b4e56b",
    "details":[
        {
            "issue":"AMOUNT_GREATER_THAN_OUTSTANDING_BALANCE",
            "description":"The new outstanding balance can not be greater than the current outstanding balance."
        }
    ],
    "links":[
        {
            "href":"https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/v1/billing/subscriptions#UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY",
            "rel":"information_link","method":"GET"
        }
    ]
}
```

**Another issue is, after creating products, plans & subscription through api, these created products, plans & subscriptions are not visible in dashboard(sandbox paypal account). but when retrieving through api i'm getting all the details. kindly tell why its happening or where to see these.**

*ps: i'm using `https://srmklive.github.io/laravel-paypal/docs.html` api for creating products/plans/subscriptions.*

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please include relevant parts of your code that produces this error.

Comment: Please include that in  your post and not in the comments.

Comment: added the code which is giving error. thanks. @ewong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PayPal Subscriptions bill automatically, according to the billing_cycles of the plan_id and/or override plan object when the subscription is created. That is the purpose of subscriptions.

When automatic payments have not been missed, there is no outstanding balance to bill. When there is no outstanding balance to bill, payment cannot be captured manually.

Comment: So basically when creating a subscription for a user for the first time, we can not capture it manually, but if next recurring bill payment missed by customer then we can capture it and so on. right? @preston-phx

Comment: It will be captured automatically when it starts. Outstanding amounts will also attempt to capture automatically at some point, unless you change this in the plan's payment_preferences. You can only attempt a manual capture when there is an outstanding amount.

Comment: Cool, thank you so much for the help. and i have one more doubt please help me to clear that. my doubt is - 
**after creating products, plans & subscription through api(srmklive/laravel-paypal package v3 & laravel 8), these created products, plans & subscriptions are not visible in dashboard(sandbox paypal account). but when retrieving through api i'm getting all the details of these. what could be the reason of this.** @preston-phx

Comment: The developer dashboard is not the sandbox account.  https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/billing/plans . If in the account you don't see plans/subscriptons, ensure you are logging into the correct sandbox account that corresponds to the REST APP/clientID you are actually using for your API operations, https://www.paypal.com/signin?intent=developer&returnUri=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.paypal.com%2Fdeveloper%2Fapplications